# How to add JFROG artifactory to the sbt.build file?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt

I'm using `sbt 1.3.9` and I need to resolve dependencies from the `Jfrog artifactory` with authorization. I have the following sbt.build file:

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.1"
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "11", "-target", "11")
resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver.ssh("my-repo", "https://artifactory.myrepo") as("usr", "password")
)
credentials += Credentials("my-repo", "https://artifactory.myrepo", "usr", "password")
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  guice,
  ...
)
```

and when I trying to build my application I have the following exception:

```
Not found
not found: /Users/john/.ivy2/local/com.examples/mylib/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/examples/mylib/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mylib-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
(ssExtractDependencies) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.examples:mylib:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Not found
Not found
not found: /Users/john/.ivy2/local/com.examples/mylib/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/examples/mylib/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mylib-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
Total time: 3 s, completed Apr 16, 2020, 3:02:27 PM
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to download jars from private artifactory, you have to specify the repositories to search and credentials:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Artifactory snapshots".at("http://X.X.X.X/artifactory/sbt-dev-local/"),
  "Artifactory releases".at("http://X.X.X.X/artifactory/sbt-release-local/"),
  "Artifactory maven releases".at(
    "http://X.X.X.X/artifactory/mvn-local-release/"
  )
)
credentials += Credentials(
  "Artifactory Realm",
  "X.X.X.X",
  "yourlogin",
  "yourpassword"
)
```

If you want to publish to JFROG artifactory repo, you have to specify credentials and `publishTo` value:

```
credentials += Credentials(
  "Artifactory Realm",
  "X.X.X.X",
  "yourlogin",
  "yourpassword"
)
publishTo := {
  if (isSnapshot.value)
    Some(
      "Artifactory Realm".at(
        "http://X.X.X.X/artifactory/sbt-dev-local;build.timestamp=" + new java.util.Date().getTime
      )
    )
  else
    Some("Artifactory Realm".at("http://X.X.X.X/artifactory/sbt-release-local"))
}
```

In my case, `X.X.X.X` is IP address. You should replace them with a real IP address or a domain

Comment: Thanks for the help! I spent half a day to find out how to solve this issue.